# How to use project ace with ionic 2

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-widget, ionic2

I am trying to build an android app with ionic 2 and using project ace to create a native android widget. Looking through the [documentation](http://microsoft.github.io/ace/docs/getting-started/) how to invoke the native code with project ace, I cannot find where to put the code to my existing javascript code to invoke the native code. Like this:

```
if (ace.platform == "Android") {
  setupWidget();
}

function setupWidget() {
  // Handle the app being resumed by a widget click:
  ace.addEventListener("android.intentchanged", checkForWidgetActivation);

  ace.android.appWidget.clear();

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ace.android.appWidget.add("Item with index " + i);
  }
}
```

All in all, where and in which file should I put the code and do I have to write a special import statement?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/ace/tree/master/examples/AceExamples here is the example plugin for ace . Please check it .Hopefully it will help you

Comment: I already looked this up,but they don't invoke the written native code from their javascript code.